# Adding a Gutenberg-like custom field on a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, block-editor

I've googled this a bunch, there's a couple of answers for old versions (pre-gutenberg) of Wordpress but none that I could find for Gutenberg.

Essentially I have a custom post type I added by editing my `functions.php` like so:

```
        // Our custom post type function
        function create_posttype() {

            register_post_type( 'Featured Sites',
            // CPT Options
                array(
                    'labels' => array(
                        'name' => __( 'Featured site' ),
                        'singular_name' => __( 'Featured sites' )
                    ),
                    'public' => true,
                    'has_archive' => true,
                    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'featured-sites'),
                    'show_in_rest' => true,
                )
            );
        }
        // Hooking up our function to theme setup
        add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

That's all working fine and dandy, but at the moment adding new content through it looks just like adding a post or a page.

Is there any way to connect custom input fields with Gutenberg blocks?

For example, could I have a block sitting on top of my post title that allows me to select certain colors, or select a specific value from a dropdown?

Something like adding a `supports` value:

```
 'supports' => array( 'my-custom-input' ),
```

Custom fields do essentially what I want, I'd just like a more visual way to associate values with my custom fields.

**Edit:**
[This plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gutenberg-custom-fields/) seems to do what I want, however I can't seem to get it working with my Custom Post Type. Unsure if I'm missing something, the documentation doesn't mention it.

Comment: Have you tried official tutorials? https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/

Comment: I have but in both the tutorial and the plugin mentioned above I can't get my custom post type to output my meta boxes in the rest API. I followed this (https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/metabox/meta-block-1-intro/), and while it works for both **posts** and **pages**, it does not work for my custom post type :(

Comment: Examples work fine for CPTs, there is nothing in Gutenberg limiting its functionality for different post types. Check that you have `'show_in_rest'  => true,` and `'supports' => array('custom-fields', ...)` when registering CPT.